# Creating a settings page like Honeycomb

Tags: android, settings, android-3.0-honeycomb, preferenceactivity

I'm making an app and I want a number of the activities to look like like the Xoom Honeycomb settings page (even though they would be showing stuff like images and videos).

http://static.intomobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/xoom-honeycomb-settings-11.png

Can most of this be done with a PreferenceActivity or does this involve a lot of custom layout design? Has anyone seen any good tutorials for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot readily show "stuff like images and videos" in a `PreferenceActivity`. What you are looking at are a pair of `ListFragments`, AFAIK.